# Why can't I upgrade compose_version from compose_version = '1.1.0-beta01' to 1.2.1?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I create an project based the wizard *Empty Compose Activity* of Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 Patch 1.  It can be compiled, and it works well.

I get the following running error after I upgrade compose_version from `compose_version = '1.1.0-beta01'` to `1.2.1`.

```
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:kotlin-extension'.
   > Could not find androidx.compose.compiler:compiler:1.2.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/compose/compiler/compiler/1.2.1/compiler-1.2.1.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/androidx/compose/compiler/compiler/1.2.1/compiler-1.2.1.pom
```

But the app can run well when I remove `kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_version` in *build.gradle (Module)*, why?

**build.gradle (Project)**

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_version = '1.1.0-beta01'  //I will upgrade it to 1.2.1
    }
}
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.5.31' apply false
}
```

**build.gradle (Module)**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdk 25
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
     
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_version //OK after I removed it
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_version"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:$compose_version"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that there is no `Compose Compiler 1.2.1` version. Currently, `Compose Compiler` follows a different release schedule than other `Compose libraries`. 
[Here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-kotlin?hl=en) is the compatibility map and the available versions of `Compose Compiler` to use together with `Kotlin`.

In case you're wondering about using different versions between `Compose Compiler` and the other `Compose libraries`, it's totally ok to do that, and that's what you should do to have access to the latest versions of them. 
You can configure your gradle as follows:

Project module

```gradle
buildscript {
    ext {
        kotlinVer = '1.7.10'
        composeCompilerVer = '1.3.1' // should be compatible with kotlin version
        composeVer = '1.2.1'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version "$kotlinVer" apply false
    // ...
}
```

App module

```gradle
// ...

android {
    // ...

    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion composeCompilerVer
    }

    // ...
}

dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$composeVer"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$composeVer"
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  Do you mean the code generated by android studio automatically is not good？ I should to set two paramters  `composeCompilerVer` and `composeVer`, right?

Comment: Yes, the default build uses the same version for Compose Compiler and others Compose library, but since Compiler now follow a different release schedule you should make some changes to uses the latest version from each one (including the Kotlin version, because it needs to be compatible with the Compose Compiler)

Answer (score 2):

The version `androidx.compose.compiler:compiler:1.2.1` doesn't exist.
You can check it in the [google maven repo](https://maven.google.com/web/index.html#androidx.compose.compiler:compiler)

You can in any case use the stable version of the module compiler `1.3.0` and all the other compose dependencies at 1.2.1:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_compiler = '1.3.0'
        compose_version = '1.2.1'
    }
    //...
}
```

and then:

```
composeOptions {
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_compiler
}

dependencies {
   // stable 1.2.1 releases
   implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
   //... 
}
```

As described in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-kotlin) the compiler 1.3.0 requires kotlin 1.7.10:

Comment: Thanks!  Do you mean the code generated by android studio automatically is not good？ I should to set two paramters  `composeCompilerVer` and `composeVer`, right?

Comment: @HelloCW Yes. the compiler has different releases