# Dolphin IDE: This version (1.2.0-alpha05) of the Compose Compiler requires Kotlin version 1.6.10 but you appear to be using Kotlin version 1.6.21

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

The error goes on to say "Please fix your configuration (or `suppressKotlinVersionCompatibilityCheck` but don't say I didn't warn you!)."

It is not obvious to me how to "fix" the configuration. I added the suggested flag, but it does not resolve and fails on its own.

The IDE is Dolphin Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1

The project sets the Kotlin version:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
```

I previously set the project to use Kotlin 1.7.10 here, but downgraded in the vain hope it would solve the issue, but it does not.

I tried adding an explicit dependency on `androidx.compose.compiler:compiler` which appears to be silently ignored.

I do not see where Kotlin 1.6.21 and Compose Compiler 1.2.0-alpha05 are being set, as neither is set in the build files.

I'm familiar with Android, but not Compose. I am using the current stable IDE and dependency statements taken directly from the Compose documentation, and yet the project fails to build.

I suspect there is some magic combination of dependency versions needed to use Compose in Dolphin, but I have not been able to find it.

I tried Compose at v1.0 but had to back out again as there were so many issues, and it seems it is still challenging to work with, but perhaps some kind soul will point out my error and then I will happily apologise to our friends at Google. :-)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'androidx.navigation.safeargs'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'

android {

    namespace "com.blah"
    
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.blah"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 123
        versionName "1.2.3"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions "environment"
    productFlavors {
        staging {
            dimension "environment"
            applicationIdSuffix ".staging"
        }
        production {
            dimension "environment"
        }
    }

    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.all { output ->
            outputFileName = "MyApp-${variant.versionName}-${variant.name}.apk"
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }
    }

    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding true
        compose true
    }

    lint {
        disable 'RtlHardcoded'
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    // Coroutines
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.2'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.2'

    // Android X Jetpack
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.5.1"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4"
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1"
    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.5.2"
    implementation "androidx.collection:collection-ktx:1.2.0"
    implementation "androidx.window:window:1.0.0"

    // Jetpack Compose
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.2.1")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:1.2.1")
    // Foundation (Border, Background, Box, Image, Scroll, shapes, animations, etc.)
    implementation("androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:1.2.1")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material:material:1.2.1")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material:material-icons-core:1.2.1")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:1.2.1")
    // Integration with observables
    implementation("androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:1.2.1")
    implementation("androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-rxjava2:1.2.1")

    // Google
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1"
    implementation 'androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.2.0'

    // Navigation Component
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.5.2"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.5.2"

    // Firebase & Crashlytics
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:21.1.1"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:21.1.1"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:18.2.13"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:21.0.1"

    // Urban Airship push messaging
    implementation "com.urbanairship.android:urbanairship-fcm:13.3.5"

    // Twilio (video calling)
    implementation "com.twilio:video-android-ktx:7.1.1"
    implementation "com.twilio:audioswitch:1.1.4"

    // ExoPlayer
    implementation "com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.18.1"
    implementation "com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.18.1"

    // Third-party
    implementation "com.jakewharton.timber:timber:5.0.1"
    implementation "com.jakewharton.threetenabp:threetenabp:1.4.0"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:2.9.0"
    implementation "com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828"
    implementation "net.yslibrary.keyboardvisibilityevent:keyboardvisibilityevent:2.3.0"
    // https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.3"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.9.3"

    // Open Source Licence List
    implementation "com.github.franmontiel:AttributionPresenter:1.0.1"

    // Shake to Send Feedback
    implementation "com.linkedin.shaky:shaky:3.0.4"
    implementation "com.jraska:falcon:2.2.0"

    // Page Indicator View
    implementation 'com.github.romandanylyk:PageIndicatorView:v.1.0.3'

    // Testing
    implementation "androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0"
    testImplementation "junit:junit:4.13.2"
    testImplementation "androidx.test:core:1.4.0"
    testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core:4.6.0"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:runner:1.4.0"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0"
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:1.2.1")

    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}
```

Module build file:

```
apply plugin: "com.github.ben-manes.versions"

buildscript {

    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.5.2"
        classpath "com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.2"
        classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14"
        classpath "com.github.ben-manes:gradle-versions-plugin:0.42.0"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        mavenCentral()

        jcenter() {
            content {
                includeModule("com.google.android", "flexbox")
            }
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Can you search for `1.6.21 ` to see if there is any usage? Maybe in places other than `build.gradle` file.

Comment: You can check the compatibility map [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-kotlin?hl=en). There is also [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73679572/18943404) where it has already been talked about this compatibility and how to configure it.

Comment: Post your build.gradle files

Comment: @Abhimanyu I searched the entire project for "1.6.21" and "1.2.0-alpha05" but neither is found. Perhaps these are set in the IDE.

Comment: @ThalesIsidoro I had checked the compatibility list, but the issue is I appear to have no way to set the Compose Compiler version or to fully set the Kotlin version Compose uses.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti Sorry for not including the build files, they are in the post now.

Comment: try to add in the `app/build.gradle` file in the `android` block     `composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion 1.3.1
    }` and use kotlin `1.7.10`

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti That's the solution. Please add it as an Answer and I will accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `app/build.gradle` file in the `android` block add:

```
android {

   //..

   composeOptions {         
       kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion "1.3.1"     
   }
}
```

According to the [compatibility map](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-kotlin?hl=en) use kotlin `1.7.10`